# How do I retrieve values from a webform?

Tags: 7, forms, webforms

I can see the values submitted in the `$_POST`, so I know they are there, but when I uses a submit handler to retrieve them, I get `NULL`. I'm fairly new to PHP so not sure if it's a simple syntax mistake or something more. Thanks.

```
function zendesk_forms_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

  if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_47') {

    $form['#submit'][] = "zendesk_forms_support_form_submit_handler";
  }
}

function zendesk_forms_support_form_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {
  form');
  $ticket = array(
      'description' => $form_state['values']['description'],
      'subject' => $form_state['values']['subject'],
  );
  echo $ticket;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ticket = array(
  'description' => $form_state['values']['submitted']['description'], 
  'subject' => $form_state['values']['submitted']['subject'],
);
```

Comment: I've tried this before but get the same result. Thanks.

Comment: I would dump $form_state['values'] into an email, file, or the watchdog log and see what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thanks to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/70895/geat for the advice of dumping the `['values']`.  I was able to access the values by key.

```
$ticket = array(
    'comment' => array(
      'description' => $form_state['values']['submitted'][6],
      'subject' => $form_state['values']['submitted'][5],
    ),
  );
```

[image]